# Programmatically configure Hadoop cluster from python

Tags: hadoop, openstack

Are there any python API's to configure a hadoop cluster (namenode, jobtracker, etc..)setup on an OpenStack cloud?? I have the IP addresss to the VM's and am looking for openstack api's to configure the same.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Hadoop API in OpenStack, but for a shameless plug I can say that [Nimbula Director](http://nimbula.com/solutions/hadoop/mapr/) does have Hadoop support tied in.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post:

https://lists.launchpad.net/openstack/msg21849.html

Mirantis is attempting to integrate a packaged hadoop deployment solution for OpenStack right now.  It looks like it will be discussed at the summit.  At the very least you should probably be able to get access to their code for this shortly and integrate yourself.

Additionally check out the HEAT API:

https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat